# Is it possible to update the color of a custom node by ID in react-flow?

Tags: reactjs, visualization

As the documentation states I am passing the props needed for custom nodes and using the nodeId prop to change the color of my nodes on click. My current workflow changes the color of all the nodes instead of just the one I clicked.

How can I change the color of the custom Node that I click?

My current workflow is as follows.

```
const [customNodeStyles, setNodeStyles] = useState({
    background: 'black',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: 10,
    height: 10
});

const onElementClick = (event, element) => {
    setNodeBg('red');
    setNodeId(element.id);
}

useEffect(() => {
    setNodeStyles({ ...customNodeStyles, background: nodeBg });

}, [nodeId, nodeBg]);

return (
    <div style={{ height: 1000, width: 1000 }}>
        <ReactFlow
            elements={elements}
            nodeTypes={{ special: CustomNodeComponent }}
            nodeTypesId={nodeId}
            onElementClick={onElementClick}
            defaultZoom={1.5}
            minZoom={0.2}
            maxZoom={4}>
        </ReactFlow>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in a nodeId into the nodeTypesId will re-render the styling for all the nodes.

What you need to do is to change the state of the backgroundColor on click. I suggest creating a React Element for your Circle Node (which will contain a div and a style element with all the necessary css fields) that gets an object and sets backgroundColor when rendered.

Comment: I am trying to do the same for my custom nodes. Is `nodeTypesId` a Prop for `<ReactFlow/>`? I don't see that in the [latest version](https://reactflow.dev/docs/api/react-flow-props/)

Comment: you shouldn't need the nodeTypesId to solve this. Let me know if you would like me to post a code snippet